# GCM Notification receiving suddenly stopped on device

Tags: android, cordova

I have strange problem. I have created acordova/phonegap application with GCM push notification. I could see the notifications were received on my device. I have tried sending again morning and none of the messages were shown on the device :(
Below is the response I am getting from GCM when I send the message from my app server

```
 {
 multicast_id: 5943010219281455000
 success: 1
  failure: 0
 canonical_ids: 1
 results: [1]
 0:  {
 registration_id:         "APA91bHiDrJxg7W_EeENTFPbEhKb5FUmuNhq7fvcQ8djKuKLZpdbznL1kCjgDvbMqCZYhtesi-vCUEIz-NO536LrICkQ2SlyXrriB07ZeoiwPAXBG-2llzUjw-7OtsMfIYyNxLKt0Adc"
message_id: "0:1443522327535490%8158da4ff9fd7ecd"
  }
   }
```

What could be the issue? Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your GCM registration id is updated or not in the server. It gets updated when the application is updated. Also it might be that there are multiple registration ids at the server end and you would be sending to the older one, try sending to the new one. 
Also be connected to internet when sending notification just to verify whether you are able to receive or not. Thanks

Comment: Now I am picking the registration id from adb logs and using that to send the push message. This is ensure I am using correct and latest one. But no luck. Is there a way to debug the issue in GCM? I mean whether device respond back to GCM with valid issue? Also do I need to look for some specific thing in adb logs? Yea device with data connectivity and I am receiving mails and other notifications

Comment: You can only debug once the notification is received by the device and not before that. Between the stage when you send from the server and till the google sends it to device, you are just dependent on google's response.